# applescript associate xml element to indesign frame

Tags: xml, applescript, adobe-indesign

I'm working with indesign and xml and I need, if possible, to associate element of xml to frame of indesign and get position of it

with applescript this is my simply code

```
tell application "Adobe InDesign CC"
set myDocument to active document
tell myDocument
    set myTag to XML tag "aa"

    tell XML element 1
        set elementCount to (get count of XML Items)
        repeat with x from 1 to elementCount
            set elem1 to XML element x
            tell contents of elem1
                set tag to value of XML attribute "ean" of elem1
            end tell
            select elem1

            /* here I try */
            set rettangolo to contents of elem1
            return geometric bounds of rettangolo as string

        end repeat
    end tell
```

and this script to get position when I select frame from indesign

```
set myDocument to active document
tell myDocument
    set rettangolo to properties of item 1 of selection
    set coordina to geometric bounds of rettangolo as string
    display dialog coordina
end tell
```

How to associate element of first script to frame ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
tell application "Adobe InDesign CC 2017"
 set myDocument to active document
 tell myDocument
  tell XML element 1
   set elementCount to (get count of XML Items)
   repeat with x from 1 to elementCount
    set elem1 to XML element x
    tell myDocument
     set myTag to XML tag (value of XML attribute "ean" of elem1 as string)
     set markup tag of elem1 to myTag
     set myStory to parent story of elem1
     set tf to item 1 of text containers of myStory
     set gbs to geometric bounds of tf as string
     display dialog gbs
    end tell
   end repeat
  end tell
 end tell
end tell
```

You should consider javascript ;)